Trying to use Femyou to run FMU (OpenModelica) but shows error "Could not find or load the native library"
I am running Visual Studio 2019. I am relatively new to this.
I need to use the Nuget Femyou, which is only available for NetStandard 2.1. (edit) I also installed the nuget NativeLibraryLoader. I initially put the target framework as .NET Standard 2.1, but I later changed to .NET CORE 3.1 after some help.
My code:
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Text;

   namespace TesteFMU_set2024
   {
      public class Program
      {
         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            TestFMU test = new TestFMU();
            test.Calculation();
            Console.Write("Calculation concluded.");
         }
      }

using System;
using Femyou;
using System.IO;

namespace TestFMU
{
    public class TestFMU
    {
        public void Calculation()
        {
            string fmuFolder = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\FMUTests\");
            using var model = Model.Load(Path.Combine(fmuFolder, "TestFemyou.fmu"));
            using var instance = Tools.CreateInstance(model, "test");
            var x = model.Variables["x"];
            var y = model.Variables["y"];
            var z = model.Variables["z"];
            Console.WriteLine("x = " + Convert.ToString(x));
        }
    }
}

However, when I try to run it, I get this error on the console:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
occurred in NativeLibraryLoader.dll Could not find or load the native
library:
C:\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Femyou\TestFemyou.fmu\binaries\win64\TestFemyou.dll


> *Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.*
And this error on the output:
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core. The program '[14520] TesteFMU_set2024.dll' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).

I checked Visual Studio Installer, but I can't figure what might be missing of .NET Core that is relevant to NetStandard 2.1. This is what I don't have installed:

.NET 5.0 Runtime (out of support)
.NET Core 2.1 Runtime (out of support)
.NET Core 2.2 Runtime (out of support)
.NET Core 3.0 Runtime (out of support)
.NET Core 3.1 Runtime (out of support)
.NET Framework 3.5 development tools
.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
.NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK
.NET Framework 4.6.2 targeting pack
.NET Framework 4.7 SDK
.NET Framework 4.7 targeting pack
.NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK
.NET Framework 4.7.1 targeting pack
.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK
.NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack
.NET Native
.NET Portable Library targeting pack
.NET SKD (out of support)
Development Tools plus.NET COre 2.1 (out of support)
Web Development Tools plus .NET Core 2.1 (out of support)

Am I missing something?
Thank you in advance!

You're using File.ReadAllText on a directory path. This method expects a file path, not a directory.

Thank you for your response. I changed to string FolderPath = $"C:\FMUTests\"; instead of using the code line I originally showed. The issue still exists, but I can't figure out why because it works when I run a program with .NET Core 3.1 as the target framework. What could it be?

You never mentioned what target framework you selected in the failing project.  It matters.

@HansPassant Sorry, I selected .NET Standard 2.1.

That is not correct, selecting .netstandard is only possible for library projects.  Do not force it.  The console project (?) must select a framework version like 4.8, .NETCore or .NET5+

Thank you! After changing the target framework to .NETCore, that specific issue disappears. There's another one now: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in NativeLibraryLoader.dll". I'll edit the original post with this error.
